# Renaming Sys.Date() Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I want to bind and rename `Sys.Date()` like this:

```
df <- df %>%
 cbind(Sys.Date()) %>%
 rename(week = Sys.Date())
```

Although I could easily rename the new Sys.Date() column with base R I'd like to pass this through a dplyr/magrittr pipe. But I get the following error message:

```
#Error: Arguments to rename must be unquoted variable names. Arguments Week are not.
```

I have a feeling that the `Sys.Date` brackets are messing things up.

Bonus: I'd also like to convert Sys.Date() to Fiscal Week at the same time.

Comment: Why not just `df %>% mutate(week = Sys.Date())`?

Comment: Also works with cbind `mtcars %>% cbind(week = Sys.Date())`

Comment: Or `df %>% mutate(week = format(Sys.Date(), "%W"))` if you need the Fiscal Week...

Comment: no worries, mine is not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David Arenburg correctly pointed out that this problem could be solved with a simple `mutate` call instead of the bare `cbind` function.

```
df %>% mutate(week = Sys.Date())
```

Thanks!